# What does linux load actually mean?

Tags: linux, multithreading, system

Does the linux load contain current running threads or just the threads number waiting for run?

Here is a snippet from *Linux System and Performance Monitoring* by Darren Hoch:
"The system load is a combination of the amount of process threads currently executing along with the amount of threads in the CPU run queue." Which I thought it's right.

But recently, I saw many people said "the load is just the thread number waiting to be scheduled on the run-queue"

So, which explanation is more accurate?

And when I was trying to figure out the above confusion, I came across a new one:

I found a rule: " 'Fix this now' Rule of Thumb: 1.00. If your load average stays above 1.00, find the problem and fix it now." from this [article](http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2009/07/31/understanding-load-averages).

Before reading this, I thought when load average stays bellow 4*cpu cores, it's still safe. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first definition is inaccurate: Currently running (executing) threads don't add to the load on most systems.

The second definition is not quite accurate either as it leaves out processes that are not runnable because they wait for I/O.

Here's a useful explanation from the `upime(1)` manual page, taken from a Debian system:

> System load averages is the average number of processes that are
>   either in a runnable or uninterruptable state. A process in a
>   runnable state is either using the CPU or waiting to use the CPU.
>   A process in uninterruptable state is waiting for some I/O
>   access, eg waiting for disk.

For a more detailed introduction, please refer to this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_%28computing%29) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Ah, a process waiting for I/O will be count into load too? Never heard this before, I need to learn more.